# Popup for a line in Mapbox GL JS, requires padding or approximate mouse-over

Tags: javascript, mapbox, mapbox-gl-js

I want to make a popup for a line in Mapbox GL JS. I have a layer that contains a lot of straight lines, defined as follows:

```
map.addLayer({id: 'lineLayer',
          type: 'line',
          source: 'lineSource',
          layout: {'line-join': 'round', 'line-cap': 'round'},
          paint: {'line-color': '#00c853','line-width': 5, 'line-opacity': 1 }});
```

Then I add a popup to a line as follows (pseudo-code):

```
map.on('mousemove', 'lineLayer', (e) => {
    map.getCanvas().style.cursor = 'pointer';
    popupCoordinatesXY = e.point; });
```

The problem is: for aesthetic reasons I don't want the lines to be too wide, but getting your mouse exactly on the line is too difficult. How do I trigger the mousemove event for a certain line even when the cursor is about 10 pixels away from it?

I have already thought about making an extra, invisible layer with wider lines, but I can imagine there is a more elegant solution.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would do what you suggest, add a new layer, but with `opacity: 0`, larger `line-width` and register the events on that layer (`opacity: 0` features are included in the results, but not if you set `visibility: none` on the layer).

The only other thing I can think of is `querySourceFeatures` and use turf to do a [`pointToLineDistance`](http://turfjs.org/docs/#pointToLineDistance) but that would be even slower and messy than just adding that invisible mouse target layer.

Comment: Thanks for the tip about opacity versus visibility. I have implemented this now, and it works fine. I guess that an extra layer is not that much of a waste after all.